# Using AWS Appflow to pull data from Google Bigquery results in a response too large error

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-appflow

I've established a workflow in Appflow that relies on a connection to BigQuery. However, when I execute the workflow, I come across an issue outlined below:

The request failed because the service Source Google BigQuery returned the following error: Details: The response size of 14.50 MB is too large. Responses can be up to 5.50 MB., ErrorCode: ClientError.

According to bigquery response limits the response could be in GB's. But in my case it fails with only 14.5MB.